# How to execute Linux command in host-machine and copy the output to image build by docker file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, boot2docker

**I want to copy the `my.cnf` file present in the host server to child docker image** wherever I run docker file that uses a custom base image having below command.

```
ONBUILD ADD locate -i my.cnf|grep -ioh 'my.cnf'|head -1 /
```

but above line is breaking docker file. Please share correct syntax or alternatives to achieve the same.

Comment: @asynts I know the command to copy normal file but here in my question as you can see am trying to copy the output of a linux command, please share command to achieve same.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't declare host commands inside your `Dockerfile`. See [Execute command on host during docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735468/execute-command-on-host-during-docker-build)
.

Your best bet is probably to tweak your deployment scripts to locate `my.cnf` on the host before running `docker build`.