# Docker container to execute a script on the host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I run a node server (in a Docker container) to listen for github webhooks, so I can redeploy when my master gets updated. My home directory contains:

```
production/
app/webhooks/
docker-compose-webhooks.yml
deploy.sh
```

**~/docker-compose-webhooks.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  webhooks:
    image: node:10.11.0-alpine
    container_name: abis-webhooks
    working_dir: /webhooks
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
      PORT: 5050
      GITHUB_SECRET: ${GITHUB_SECRET}
    expose:
      - '5050'
    volumes:
      - ./app/webhooks:/webhooks
    command: /bin/sh -c 'npm install --production; npm start'
```

**~/deploy.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/production && git pull origin master
...
...
```

What's the easiest way I can call the **deploy.sh** that is obviously located outside the container where node sits.

I took this from another post and add it in node:

```
exec(`docker run --rm -v /usr/bin:/usr/bin --privileged -v $(pwd)/depoly.sh:~/deploy.sh ubuntu bash ~/deploy.sh`)
```

Comment: There is a similar question here: [How to run shell script on host from docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163955/how-to-run-shell-script-on-host-from-docker-container). Be careful of the security risks you might have by following this approach.

Comment: that's where I found the `docker run --rm` but no success executing that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run shell script on host from docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163955/how-to-run-shell-script-on-host-from-docker-container)

Comment: I saw that post, but I don't see where it should be run from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use named pipes as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719458/7475450

Or, you can execute the script on the host via `ssh` from the container. Example:

```
docker_hostname="my-host"
docker_host_user="jimmyneutron"
ssh $docker_host_user@$docker_hostname 'echo $HOSTNAME' # returns: my-host
ssh $docker_host_user@$docker_hostname '~/deploy.sh'    # run script on my-host
```

If needed you can setup public key based authentication for passwordless ssh access on the host. See https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-passwordless-ssh-login/