# Execute a python script (on local machine) from another script inside a docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, execution

So I have a script, **`a.py`**, on my local machine **which will only work on Windows operating system** since it uses certain packages that only work on Windows.

I have another script, **`b.py`**. I am using the below code to execute `a.py` from `b.py` and get the output.

```
command = [sys.executable, 'a.py', '-i', some_argument]
process = subprocess.check_output(command).decode()
```

The problem is `b.py` is in a docker container and `a.py` is in the host machine. I'm running a Linux container since Windows container was having a lot of other problems.

I have thought of using Volumes on docker. But I'm assuming, by using volumes, a new directory is made in the Docker's storage directory and it will try to run `a.py` in the Linux container (which wont work because script only works on Windows).

So is there a way for `b.py` (in container) to execute `a.py` (in host machine)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run shell script on host from docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163955/how-to-run-shell-script-on-host-from-docker-container)

Comment: The short answer is “no, Docker is explicitly designed so you can’t do that”, though the answers to that question provide several specific-case workarounds.