# Restart a docker container from another running container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose for deployment.
I want to restart my "centos-1" container from "centos-2" container. Both containers are running on the same host.
Please suggest, How could I achieve this in a simplest and automated way?

I followed [How to run shell script on host from docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163955/how-to-run-shell-script-on-host-from-docker-container) and tried to run a script on Host from "centos-2" container, but the script is executing inside a container and not on the host.

Script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo docker container restart centos-1
```

Error:

```
    line 2: docker: command not found
```

(Docker isn't installed inside any centos-2 container)

Comment: You can’t do this without giving the “centos-2” container unrestricted root-level access over the host: be very very careful with security concerns if you try one of the answers below.  A better approach might be an HTTP endpoint on “centos-1” that caused it to shut itself down, without anything Docker-specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need:

1. Install docker CLI (command line interface) on second container. Do not confuse with full scale installation - you dont need docker daemon, only command line tool (`docker` executable)
2. Share you **host's** docker daemon (service) to make it accessible in **second container**. That is achieved with simply sharing `/var/run/docker.sock` when launching 2nd container, example:

   ```
   docker run ... -v "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" container2 ...
   ```
3. Now you can execute any docker command, like `docker stop` from second container and these commands are happily passed to your main (and the only) docker daemon.

Comment: Worked perfectly.Thanks..!

Answer (score 3):

There is a approach from the CI-context to control the Docker Daemon on System from a running container called Docker-out-of-Docker (DooD):

1. you have to install docker inside your container
2. Map you docker installation from your system inside your container using `volumes`

```
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Now each docker command inside your container are execute on the system docker installation. E.g. if you type `docker image list` inside your container there should be the same list as if your type the command on your system.