# Enter host namespace from privileged container

Tags: docker, namespaces, containers, host

My app runs as a privileged docker container on linux hosts. Inside the app I want to execute a command on the host system and get the output. What is the best way to do it. Can nsenter be helpful?

Comment: The best way to do this is to run your process outside Docker.  You might be able to do complicated things with namespaces to escape a privileged container, but then you're not really getting any advantage from the Docker setup.

Comment: @DavidMaze Could you elaborate how to take advantage of docker environment

Comment: @ShayK I am executing an rpm query. I want to execute this query on the host from my app which is running in a privileged container.

Comment: Docker is an isolation environment that's especially good at packaging self-contained network servers.  Since it's an isolation environment, it's especially bad at tasks that involve administering the host the container runs on, or at managing the host's filesystem.  If you want to manage things like the host's installed packages you need to run this task completely outside of Docker.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49873529/2879188

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.

```bash
docker run --privileged --pid=host -it alpine:3.8 \
  nsenter --target 1 --mount --uts --net --ipc sh
```

First, we start a `--privileged` container which does not create its own pid namespace (`--pid=host`). Therefore, pid 1 in the container is the pid 1 outside the container, which is some kind of `init`, probably `systemd`.

Then, we use `nsenter` to enter the `--mount`, `--uts`, `--net`, and `--ipc` namespaces of the pid 1 process (that's `--target 1`) and run `sh`. This shell is now effectively outside the container.

Depending on the host system, you may need to add a `--security-opt` to disable AppArmor, Seccomp, or Selinux, if some of this is active.

```
--security-opt apparmor=unconfined
--security-opt seccomp=unconfined
--security-opt label:disable
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is doable!

Check out [this blog](https://medium.com/lucjuggery/a-container-to-access-the-shell-of-the-host-2c7c227c64e9)