# Writing to the directory of Host OS - Passing the instruction with docker-compose file

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, devops

If an application is running inside a docker and wants to write to `/etc/nginx/conf.d` directory of host OS, how could I pass on this instruction in the `docker-compose` file? SO whenever an attempt to write to `/etc/nginx/conf.d` is made, it writes into the file of the host OS
This is how my docker-compose.yml looks right now

```
myapp:
 container_name: myapp
 restart: always
 build: .
 ports:
   - "3001:3001"
```

Comment: Have you tried [using volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I went through this document before posting here. But I could not understand, how exactly to use this for my case. Could you help answer this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker volumes 
: Mount host paths or named volumes, specified as sub-options to a service.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

```
myapp:
 container_name: myapp
 restart: always
 build: .
 ports:
   - "3001:3001"
 volumes:
   - <your_host_pc_path>:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Whenever /etc/nginx/conf.d is changed in the docker container, `<your_host_pc_path>` is also changed.
Likewise, even if a change in `<your_host_pc_path>` occurs, `/etc/nginx/conf.d` of the docker container is changed.

Comment: And how could I run a command on the host from docker? A script running inside docker has to run a command present on docker.

Comment: [How to run shell script on host from docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163955/how-to-run-shell-script-on-host-from-docker-container)