# From within a container, how to know if running in rootless mode?

Tags: docker

Since Docker 20.10, [it supports running the daemon in rootless mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/).

It's possible to know if the docker daemon is running in rootless mode through `docker info`:

```
$ docker info
[...]
Server:
 [...]
 Security Options:
  rootless
 [...]
```

My question is: from within a container (i.e. in the `entrypoint`), how can I check if it is running in `rootless` mode?

PS: without relying on the user namespace detection, [as not all the `userns` scenarios are tied to docker daemon's `rootless` mode](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/pull/2492#issuecomment-940467426).

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the docker context.
Use the following command:

`docker context inspect`

If you running a rootless context, you will get an output similar to the following one:

[image]

Also, you can get info using the command:

`docker info`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this within the container? If so, I have to install the docker cli within it too, right?

Comment: @feliperks Sorry, my fault. I didn't notice you asked, "from within a container". So my answer is no, it’s from the host. Accessing the host from within a container breaks the isolation concept.  Other approaches using mounted named pipes, ssh, etc. (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163955/how-to-run-shell-script-on-host-from-docker-container) ) require also some work to be done in the host system. But if you have access to the host, running a rootless Docker installation, you also have access to Docker CLI (e.g.: via the docker info you also mentioned).